# How to create a "stretchable" UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation

I have a UIView that contains another UIView.  The outer UIView draws a border around the inner UIView via `drawRect`.  (The border is too complicated to be drawn via CALayer properties.)

At present, when I animate the resizing of the outer UIView, its `drawRect` method is called once at the beginning of the animation and the result is stretched or shrunk.  This does not look good.

I am looking for a way to either redraw the content at every step of the animation, or find a way to achieve the same visual effect.  (The result should be similar to the resizing of a stretchable UIImage.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding subviews with autoresizing masks that kept them positioned correctly during the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You should change view's content type to:

```
your_view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

And it will redraw each time its frame changes.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, since the frame only changes once.

Answer (score -1):

You need to send a [UIView setNeedsToDisplay] to the view for every time the frame size is changed, you could try overriding the setFrame: method like

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)r
{
    [super setFrame:r];
    [self setNeedsToDisplay];
}
```

Comment: You don't have to call `setNeedsDisplay` if your view has `contentMode == UIViewContentModeRedraw`.